# consuming web service using wsdl

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have a java web service deployed on my local Tomcat server. I am able to access it through a java client from my local machine.
I would like to access the same service from a remote machine in the same network.
On the remote machine I generated the client for the web service using the wsdl url.
however the soap address location in wsdl is as shown below:
`<wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloService/services/Hello"/>`
To use this client to access the service would it be enough to change all references to localhost with the machine IP on which the service is deployed... ?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to edit the WSDL; you can [set the end-point in the port](http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.com/2009/02/jax-ws-how-to-configure-service-end_17.html) programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just change localhost to your network hostname or ip address

Comment: You mean changing in the client files generated using the wsdl... Am I right?

Comment: i`ve used this solution in my projects for connecting between java and c# applications